# Apache mod_rewrite rule to only show specific folder based on domain

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I would like to create an apache rewrite rule that would only display a subfolder based on used the domain name.

Context:
domain.com and domain2.com points to the same folder.

Situation:
Accessing www.domain.com/domain.com/myfile.jpg would work while www.domain2.com/domain.com/myfile.jpg would return a 404 error.

I believe mod_rewrite could help me achieve this.
Any directions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to hide a subfolder containing the second domain, you could put the following in the `.htaccess` file in the common folder to force a not found error:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain2.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/domain.com/?.*)$ /some-nonexistent-file [L]
```

A more useful thing to do might be to reroot both domains to subfolders:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /domain.com/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain2.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /domain2.com/$1 [L]
```